# Inline Font Declaration in nuxt.config.js (Nuxt)

Tags: css, fonts, nuxt.js, inline, vue-meta

Is below the proper way to inline font declaration in head tag in nuxt.config.js. Trying to follow best practices for font loading strategies from https://web.dev/font-best-practices/. The style tag doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help?!

```
link: [
  { rel: 'preconnect', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com' },
  { rel: 'dns-prefetch', href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com' },
  {
    rel: 'preconnect',
    href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com',
    crossorigin: 'anonymous',
  },
  {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;700&subset=latin&display=swap',
  },
  { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
],

style: [
  {
    cssText:
      '@font-face { font-family: "Inter", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segou UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif }',
    type: 'text/css',
  },
  {
    cssText:
      'body { font-family: "Inter", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segou UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif }',
    type: 'text/css',
  },
],
```

Comment: `style` is to link global CSS. This is not intended to anything else. Beyond that, what is `cssText`? If you want to have it as a font, set it into a `.css` file. Also, don't overthink it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. In regards to cssText I was just following reference from vue-meta. ==> https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#style.  Just wanted to know if there was a way to inline @font-face in head because this was suggested via web.dev article as best practice preferred over preload. Article ==>https://web.dev/font-best-practices/ I probably am overthinking it. Once again thanks so much.

Comment: ... I do have my global in main.css in assets. I guess thats good enough

Comment: Nuxt will already use some prebuilt above the fold CSS inlin-ing so yeah, IMO it's fine to do it this way!

Comment: Thanks so much!!